# OpenShift - When is a service created while creating a new application?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, openshift, strimzi

I created two applications `wurstmeister/kafka` and `zookeeper` as shown below.

```sh
oc new-app wurstmeister/kafka
oc new-app zookeeper
```

While I can see the `zookeeper` service in my project, I do not see the Kafka service. How do I get my others pods connect to Kafka? Through the pod IP address? But, isn't `service` the way for the pods to connect with each other?

Why wasn't the service for Kafka created automatically?

[Kafka Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/dockerfile)
[Zookeeper Dockerfile](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/5a82d0b90d055f39d50e0a64ae2e00da15f9b8b1/3.4.14/Dockerfile)

Comment: The Kafka `Dockerfile` doesn't include an `EXPOSE` instruction so `oc new-app` can't know what ports need to be exposed and so cannot create a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to the fact that while the Zookeeper Dockerfile contains an EXPOSE line exposing the ports, there is no such a line in the Kafka Dockerfile which is actually not exposing the default 9092 port for example.
The new-app command exposes the declared ports through a service only in case you are actually exposing ports via EXPOSE.

Because you are trying to deploy Kafka on OpenShift, I suggest to take a look at the Strimzi project (https://strimzi.io/), it will make your life easier.
It provides a cluster operator to install in the OpenShift cluster and then describing a Kafka cluster through a Kafka resource; the operator will deploy the cluster for you.

Comment: I tried installing `strimzi`; the `oc wait` does not complete and the pod crashes with this message: `WatchConnectionManager:194 - Exec Failure: HTTP 403, Status: 403 - kafkas.kafka.strimzi.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:messaging-os:strimzi-cluster-operator" cannot watch kafkas.kafka.strimzi.io in the namespace "messaging-os": no RBAC policy matched`

Comment: Did you follow the extra "sed" step for updating installation file with the right namespace before deploying? see here https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#deploying-cluster-operator-str the "sed" command stuff.

Comment: No, I was following the instructions here https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/okd/ . I have the Kafka cluster up now, thanks!